# How to configure GitLab's phpcs-security-audit analyzer?

Tags: php, gitlab, gitlab-ci, phpcs, sast

I am trying to use [`phpcs-security-audit`](https://github.com/FloeDesignTechnologies/phpcs-security-audit) by including [GitLab's SAST template](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/sast/#configure-sast-manually). It generates a report as expected, but the report is filled with warnings from libraries and specific warnings that I would like to ignore for the report to be useful.

If I ran `phpcs` and `phpcs-security-audit` myself, I could [store settings in a config file](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Advanced-Usage#using-a-default-configuration-file). Storing settings in `.phpcs.xml` works locally, but has no effect on GitLab's [`phpcs-security-audit` analyzer](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/analyzers/phpcs-security-audit). I can't find any documentation for it. Is it possible to configure the analyzer, and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. It's simple, create directory `.gitlab`, inside that create file called `sast-ruleset.toml`. In the `sast-ruleset.toml`, add this following code:

```
[phpcs-security-audit]
  [[phpcs-security-audit.ruleset]]
    disable = true

    [phpcs-security-audit.ruleset.identifier]
    type = "phpcs_security_audit_source"
    value = "PHPCS_SecurityAudit.BadFunctions.FilesystemFunctions.WarnFilesystem"
```

`value` is warning that you want to ignore, you can get the value in the Security Tab, go to the warning and select the Identifiers.

[image: Scan Output Example]

See the [Gitlab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/sast/customize_rulesets.html) for more details.

Comment: Not trying this right now, but it looks like it would be right. Thanks!